# display shadow for gorhom bottom sheet in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, bottom-sheet

I am using gorhom react-native-bottom-sheet. I need to show the shadowBox when user is swiping the bottom sheet up or down. How to do it and is it possible? For now I have set it to show on isOpen but need to show it on swipe. I also tried to wrap it inside a touchable that triggers isPressed to true and shows the ShadowBox, but it did not work when moving the bottom sheet.

```
 export default function BottomSheet() {
        const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);
        const { t } = useTranslation();
        const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const bottomSheetModalRef = useRef(null);

    const snapPoints = ["50%"];

    function handlePresentModal() {
        bottomSheetModalRef.current?.present();
        setTimeout(() => {
            setIsOpen(true);
        }, 100);
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Button title="Present Modal" onPress={handlePresentModal} />
            <BottomSheetModalProvider>
                <StatusBar style="auto" />
                <BottomSheetModal
                    ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
                    index={0}
                    snapPoints={snapPoints}
                    handleComponent={CustomHandler}
                    onDismiss={() => setIsOpen(false)}
                >
                    <Spacer size={30} />
                    <BottomSheetScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
                   //Content here
                    </BottomSheetScrollView>
                </BottomSheetModal>
            </BottomSheetModalProvider>
            {isOpen && <ShadowBox />}
        </>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    contentContainer: {
        paddingHorizontal: 16,
        paddingBottom: 100,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,It's possible ,
You need to use this library for dropshadow for any components.

[Click this link for library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-drop-shadow)

Let me know anything require!.

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible by adding a couple of functions to your code. Add **handleSheetChanges** function ,to track the changes to show the shadowBox component  ,

```js
  function handleSheetChanges(index) {
    if (index !== -1) {
      setIsOpen(true);
    } else {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  }
```

And add this function in the property of the BottomSheetModal's **handleSheetChanges** attribute as below to listen to the state change

```js
   <BottomSheetModal
          ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
          index={0}
          snapPoints={snapPoints}
          handleComponent={CustomHandler}
          onDismiss={() => setIsOpen(false)}
          handleSheetChanges={handleSheetChanges} // Listen to sheet state changes
        >
```

Try this.